# USB fails to be mounted or detected on Debian machine

Tags: linux, usb, debian

My `lsusb` command says this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0951:1642 Kingston Technology DT101 G2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My `dmesg` after the detection of usb - Nothing is printed post this.:

```
[ 2583.385758] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 2583.562176] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1642
[ 2583.562364] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2583.562525] usb 2-1: Product: DT 101 G2
[ 2583.562668] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 2583.562804] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 001372982B41BA71600001D2
```

Finally, output of `blkid` and `fdisk -l`:

```
root@debian:/dev/bus/usb/002# blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="0081c97a-b3df-4abc-a935-04f44d6b15c4" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda1: UUID="ec7d27eb-f62b-407c-b22b-d47fff502452" TYPE="ext4"
root@debian:/dev/bus/usb/002# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00067788

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 15988735 7993344 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 15990782 16775167 392193 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 15990784 16775167 392192 82 Linux swap / Solaris
root@debian:/dev/bus/usb/002#
```

And still I can't mount my USB. Why is that?

Comment: Are there partitions and filesystems on the stick?

Comment: @Jan,yups. FAT32 partition but no partitions.

Comment: No partitions? You've written a FAT32 FS to the raw device?

Comment: @Jan, the USB is already in use, and I use it routinely on my other machines, Ubuntu and Win 7. I am trying to use it on my Debian machine but it fails to load it.